# How to infer different typehint for class and instance variables?

Tags: sqlalchemy, orm, type-hinting, sqlmodel

## **Some context**

I am prototyping a custom ORM inspired by [SQLModel](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/) and SQLAlchemy.
I tested both and they seem to have different annotation behaviour for fields.

Let's consider the two following implementations of a `User` model in those two frameworks:

SQLModel:

```py
from typing import Optional

from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field, Session, select
from sqlmodel import create_engine


class User(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = "user_account"
    id: Optional[int] = Field(primary_key=True, default=None)
    name: str


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create database
    engine = create_engine("sqlite+pysqlite:///:memory:")
    SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)
    session = Session(engine)
    # Add some test data
    test = User(name="test")
    session.add(test)
    session.commit()
    # Test a query
    stmt = select(User).where(User.name.in_(["test"]))
    for user in session.scalars(stmt):
        print(user.name)
```

SQLAlchemy:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, String, select
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Session, Mapped, mapped_column


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create database
    engine = create_engine("sqlite+pysqlite:///:memory:")
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    session = Session(engine)
    # Add some test data
    test = User(name="test")
    session.add(test)
    session.commit()
    # Test a query
    stmt = select(User).where(User.name.in_(["test"]))
    for user in session.scalars(stmt):
        print(user.name)
```

- SQLModel infer the type properly on the instances of the class. PyCharm linter properly indicates `user.name` is a string. However `User.name.in_` is seen as an error. This is not really practical if we need to pass filtering object to/from functions. Note that `mypy` fails on this implementation.
- SQLAlchemy does the opposite: `User.name.in_` is properly type checked but the `user.name` is not. Passing model instance attributes to function is not very handy as there is basically no type checking. Here `mypy` gives expected success.

Above implementations were tested with sqlmodel-0.0.14 and SQLAlchemy-2.0.26 on Python 3.11.

Just for clarification, I am not planning on using any SQLModel nor SQLAlchemy for my project. They are just a inspiration for elaborating a completely different ORM not even based on SQL databases.

## **Best of both worlds?**

While keeping the model implementation as concise as possible, I'd like to provide a proper type checking for both class variables and instance variables.

My guess is that both SQLModel and SQLAlchemy rely on meta-classes for dealing with the field/attribute parts which makes proper type checking not possible but I might be wrong.

Considering the following (crud) base implementation, is there a way to provide type hints so both class and instance variable are properly type checked and where PyCharm's linter properly autocomplete `Example.name` and `model_instance.name`?

```py
class Field:

    def filter(self):
        pass


class BaseModel(object):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # Crud way of setting the instance variables
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)


class ExampleModel(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert isinstance(ExampleModel.name, Field)
    model_instance = ExampleModel(name="test")
    assert isinstance(model_instance.name, str)
```

Comment: *Type-checking* your implementation can be done if you implement `BaseModel` with [`typing[_extensions].dataclass_transform`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.dataclass_transform). For PyCharm to let you autocomplete, they need to support `typing.dataclass_transform`, which they don't appear to as of now (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-54560).